# Can I attach a ssh session to an x2go session display?

Tags: ssh, x11, x2go

When working from home, there are some manipulations that I must do on a distant machine, in the office.

I mainly have to work on a terminal, but sometimes I need to use a software with a heavy GUI (started from the terminal).

Because the software is too heavy for X forwarding through SSH, I use x2go to start a terminal and work on this terminal.
But it seems to me that it is a bit overkill (and slow) to start a terminal through x2go and transfer graphical information instead of using a ssh connection for the terminal work and use x2go only for the graphical software.

Basically what I would like to do is:

1. Start an x2go session (on nothing specific)
2. Connect to the server using ssh
3. Launch the graphical software in the ssh shell using the x2go session as display

Is there a way to do this?

I already tried to set DISPLAY to the value set in the terminal opened in x2go but it doesn't work.

```
> DISPLAY=:88 xterm

No protocol specified
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :88
```

Comment: For further exploring, you could try: 1) Start an xterm in the X2Go session, 2) Launch tmux in there, 3) try to start graphical App from tmux child shell, 4) If that works, connect via ssh to the X2Go host, and `tmux attach`. 5) Test-Launch another graphical App, 6) Close xterm that originally launched tmux. 7) If you are still connected to tmux over SSH, you should probably still be able to launch X Apps. Not a solution, but a workaround. If it doesn't work, add some more info to your Question.

Comment: This works until point 6. I think that closing the application started by X2Go stops the X2Go session altogether.
Also, only the tmux windows opened on the X2Go terminal can open graphical Apps, not the one I open in the tmux session I attached to via ssh.
Although not a solution, this workaround is enough for me. Thanks !

Comment: @mokkoppe you probably just need a few more environment variables. Try opening via x2go an xterm and in it do `export -p >file` (assuming bash). Then in your ssh login set the environment in the shell with `source ./file` and try to run your X11 app. You will need to keep the original xterm open.

Comment: @meuh I did that and it worked as wanted. adding the environment variables one after the other, I found that these four were enough to start xterm: `DISPLAY LD_LIBRARY_PATH NX_XINERAMA_CONF PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG`.
I haven't tested all the functionalities of X2Go though,maybe some other variables are needed for other functionalities.